# JS/PHP POST to php script for database query

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, mariadb

I'm trying to get Input from a User and then Post it to another PHP Script to use the input for a MariaDB query.

**Index.php:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device.width, inital-scale=1">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- jQuery UI library -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
    href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Initialise autocomplete -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
   
</head>

<body>
   <form>
      <input type="text" id="name" name="search" placeholder="Enter Gene Name...">
      <button id="searchBtn" type="button" name="btn" onclick="post()" >Search</button>
   </form>
      
    <script>
        function post() {
        var name = document.getElementById("name").value;

        $.ajax({
                type : "POST", 
                url  : "search.php",  
                data : { name : name},
                success: function(res){  
                        }
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Search.php**

```
<?php    
$name = $_POST['name'];

echo $name;

$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = '****';
$dbpass = '****';
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

// select and print all from database
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM cardiomic_database.genes WHERE gene LIKE '%".$name."%'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row["gene"]. "<br>";
  }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

I assume there are many mistakes. The idea is to get the user input in the text file with id="name" which should be posted to search.php and there be used in the DB query. I don't have any errors it is just not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: why you are using ajax? you need the page NOT to be reloaed?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/submitting-ajax-forms-with-jquery

Comment: What **exactly** is not working with that code? What have you tried to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can derive issue in form event. Please keep below form only and remove all other forms and let me know if issue persist.

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="search" placeholder="Enter Gene Name...">
    <button id="searchBtn" type="button" name="btn" onclick="post()" >Search</button>
</form>
```

Please try to update post function as below.

```
<script>
    function post() {
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;

    $.ajax({
            type : "POST", 
            url  : "search.php",  
            data : { name : name},
            success: function(res){ 
                $("body").prepend(res); 
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you wanna use ajax here..?, while you can simply submit the form to the php file directly.

```
<form method="post" action="search.php">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="search" placeholder="Enter Gene Name...">
    <button id="searchBtn" type="submit" name="btn">Search</button>
</form>
```

If you really wanna use ajax then I don't see any problem here TBH, but my way of using it would be.

```
$.post("search.php", {
           name : name
        }, function (data, status) {
        //  alert (data + '\n' + "status" + status);
            if (status === 'error') {
                console.log("error"); // For debugging purpose
            } else if (status === 'success') {
              console.log("dont");
            }
        });
```